# How to insert document onto mongoDB database on mLab?

Tags: java, mongodb, mlab

Currently, my java program can insert to and query from MongoDB localhost (my laptop). Everything works perfect. So now I want to move the database on Cloud so I create MongoDB deployment on mLab using free Sandbox plan (500 MB). I have also add a user for the database.

So I follow the instruction to connect using uri by replacing

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
```

with

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://[myusername]:[mypassword]@ds033046.mlab.com:33046/ureca");
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
```

I did put the actual username and password.

```
// Access a specific database
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("ureca"); // database name is ureca
// Access collection fingerprints (if not available, auto generate)
MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("fingerprints");
```

However, it seems odd that when I run the code, the collection is created on the database but document is not inserted into the collection.

This is the insert code:

```
collection.insertOne(document);
```

Instead, the Timeout error is displayed.

Ps. The fact that "fingerprints" collection is created online reflects that my program can connect with the database but cannot insert document.

Comment: Can you include the actual error message?